# HIde sys_file_reference field in special tt_content type

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I am trying to hide the sys_file_reference.description field in my custom tt_content CE type.

Hiding the field for ALL of tt_content (and pages) works like this

`TCEFORM.sys_file_reference.description.disabled = 1`

Hiding a tt_content field for a certain CE type works like this

`TCEFORM.tt_content.header.types.mycustomtype.disabled = 1`

Hiding the field from the pages sys_file_reference works like this

`TCEFORM.pages.description.types.sys_file_reference.disabled = 1`

However, combining the three does nothing for me:

`TCEFORM.tt_content.description.types.mycustomtype.disabled = 1`
`TCEFORM.sys_file_reference.description.types.mycustomtype.disabled = 1`
`TCEFORM.tt_content.description.types.sys_file_reference.types.mycustomtype.disabled = 1`

Is there a way? A TCA solution would be fine, too.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

TCA Solution:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['mycustomtype']['columnsOverrides']['mycolumn']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']['description'] = [
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'passthrough'
    ]
];
```